# MySQL strange behaviour: "b'schemaname'" schema is created

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

this is my frist time posting something like this but im pulling my hair our, for days on end i have been trying to debug and find what is wrong with mysql, i run a gameserver and use mysql to store all the players information, like items, clothes etc, i recently came into this issue, i can no longer run sql scripts, when i try an error is thrown and a new schema is created with the name of the current schema im trying to run the script in, but it creates it like this b'schemaname' (schemaname being what the name of my schema is that im trying to run the script on), now i have reinstalled mysql and to no luck the issue still persists, i have included a video to show exactly what i mean and what is happening. ----> https://youtu.be/l6o4r5jtpcU  <------ I appreciate every and anyone that helps, its not too big of an issue as i can still run the scripts a different way but still, i have no idea what has caused this or a fix for it, thank you

Comment: Not allowed to youtube.. please include everything needed to reproduce the issue in the question, no links please.

Comment: how is your problem realted to Lua? you never leave the SQLWorkbench